# AWS - API Gateway - adding query string parameter via mapping template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, integration, amazon-sns, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to do this?

#### My use case

I'm trying to integrate API gateway and SNS, but every guide/tutorial I found get the TopicArn from the gateway incoming requeste, i.e. from the user call, but since my endpoint will push to a single topic I want to avoid this step, having the API gateway adding it (hardcoded) to the integration request.

AFAIK the only way to do this is via mapping template, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

It was easy and probably I was making some typos at the beginning, so that's why I wasn't succeeding.

- `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` [`Integration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-uri) property docs
- [Amazon API Gateway API request and response data mapping reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html)

#### Cloudformation template relevant code

```yaml
Resources:
    ApiGatewayMethod:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
        Properties:
            Integration:
                RequestParameters:
                    integration.request.querystring.<query-param-name>: 
                IntegrationResponses:
                    - StatusCode: '200'<desired value>
            MethodResponses:
                - StatusCode: '200'
                  ResponseModels:
                      application/json: "Empty"
```